# WordPress - WP Contact Form 7 issue

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I am facing a strange issue, I have set a TO emails address as "request@workreign.com" in the WP Contact form 7 mail settings, that means the form should be emailed to this emails ID.

But, instead, the form is getting sent to the person who submits the form. Please refer this video screen recording - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F3r9bRDuGs

In this recording, I filled the form with "mack.co.in@gmail.com" email ID and this form is supposed to be sent to "request@workreign.com" but instead, it is getting sent to "mack.co.in@gmail.com" only.

Comment: Helpers will generally not leave this site to watch a YouTube video of the problem. You could upload a screencast GIF if you can keep it to a reasonable download size (I believe that can be shown directly on the official image upload CDN of Stack Overflow). Or, failing that, describe the problem in the question instead.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.